# Customized Divi Theme Needs more Menus

Tags: menus

I have a customized Divi theme built by a marketing agency that I no longer partner with. My theme only supports three menus (header, secondary, and footer), which are all used; however, now my not-for-profit has a new initiative that needs a separate header menu for at least six months until it gains legs and we rebuild an entirely new website. I do not have coding experience and need help!

My website is https://www.bioforward.org/, and it currently has a simplified header menu that expands to show an extensive menu. Any advise on where I should start to complete this work in-house so I can patch this together until my website is rebuilt?

Comment: If you don't have coding experience, you should probably try to find a WordPress developer to have a look at this. If you *really* want to do this yourself, your active theme's `functions.php` file is where I'd start looking for customizations.

Answer (score 0):

Login and try to go to https://www.bioforward.org/wp-admin/nav-menus.php or select appearance>menus in the back end dashboard from the left side. Click "create a new menu" and give you menu a name like "Temp Menu" or "New Menu". Select posts or pages from the left hand side and click "add to menu" and organize as you like. Then click the check box for "Primary Menu" and click the "Save Menu" button. This should replace your main menu. There a literally thousand of youtube videos on how the WordPress menus work as well as everything else you'd like to learn about WordPress. It's all doable but it will take a great deal of trial and error and time.  You may also find this post useful: https://www.divithemeexamples.com/how-to-build-a-divi-menu/ Good luck!